# how to find the median in the list with removing the nan in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to make a function which return a list of median values for a list, below is my example :

`y=[1,3,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,5,2,4]`

I would like to calculate the median for each set of elements which are not zero in my case the answer will be 
`[3.0, 2.0, 3.5, 4.0]`
I wrote the below function but I am sure it's not the most pythonic way specially that I receive a warning that I am calculating the ("Mean of an empty slice")

```
def my_func(list1):
  median = 0
  list2 = []
  total = []

  for i in list1:
    if i != 0:
      total.append(i)
    else:
      median = np.median(total)
      list2.append(median)
      newList = [i for i in list2 if not math.isnan(i)]
      total = []

return (newList)
```

Is there any other practical way to do the same operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from statistics import median
>>> y=[1,3,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,5,2,4]
>>> [ median(g) for k,g in groupby(y, lambda x: x!=0) if k ]
[3, 2, 3.5, 4]
>>>
```

as you separate the elements in a sort of split in the zeroes, then I use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do just that, here `k` would be either true or false accordingly to me grouping function and `g` would contains those elements that are non-zero when `k` is true and vice-versa, and I use the list comprehension to filter those elements, as illustrated bellow

```
>>> [ list(g) for k,g in groupby(y, lambda x: x!=0) if k ]
[[1, 3, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 5, 4, 2], [1, 4, 5, 2, 4]]
>>>
```

then I use [statistics.median](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median) to get the desire result

or with `numpy` if you prefer, but that might be a litter overkill for just this

```
>>> [ numpy.median(list(g)) for k,g in groupby(y, lambda x: x!=0) if k ]
[3.0, 2.0, 3.5, 4.0]
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot it seems to work , I need to check the itertools more

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise way, although arguably less readable.

This uses [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which groups consecutive elements by the result of a given key function. In this case, the key function is whether the elements are zeros.

```
y = [1,3,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,5,4,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,4,5,2,4]
groups = [list(group) for is_zero, group in 
          itertools.groupby(y, lambda a: a == 0) if not is_zero]]
medians = [np.median(group) for group in groups]
```